# How can I customize a Codename One side Menu?

Tags: codenameone

Is there a builder for customizing the theme.css developed by the Initializr, or a tutorial for doing it manually? I have opened the GUI Builder form I created and it no longer has the theme on the left wing. I am running through the tutorial to "Create a Gorgeous SideMenu", but things are different now than they were back then. Does anyone have a code example I can study?

Answer (score 1):

You can style/design content of a sidemenu the usual way you style the look & feel of a user input `Form` using `icons, buttons, labels, containers & CSS` and add all these to a  `Container` with `BoxLayout.y()`. Then you can set this container as the content of a sidemenu using `form.getToolbar().addComponentToSideMenu(container)`

For a sample, check out `sideMenuItems()` function of [this dashboard](https://github.com/Eric-Chomba/FeaturesCN1-Maven/blob/master/common/src/main/java/com/zomuhtech/cn/features/Dashboard.java) which returns a container with contents of a sidemunu

Answer (score 0):

Some of the newer courses [here](https://debugagent.com/series/cn1) use CSS. Notice you can just edit the CSS and the simulator will update instantly as you save, no need to restart. You can use standard simple CSS (no positioning or complex selectors etc.) and refer to the [developer guides CSS section](https://codenameone.com/developer-guide.html#_css) for some of the Codename One specific equivalents.

If you have a specific difficulty related to a tutorial designed prior to the move to CSS I can help with that.